Issue while using circle_dat function from GOplot
I am having issue with the circle_dat() command from the GOplot package. I have two data files: one for my GO analysis results (GoList), and one for my DEG gene list/analysis results (genelist), as specified in the github for the GOplot package.
I'm trying to generate a GOcircle() plot. Here is my code:
genelist <- read.csv('2hGeneComparison2.csv')
GoList <- read.csv('ResultsGo3.csv')
circ <- circle_dat(GoList, genelist)
GOCircle(circ)

head(circ) returns the following, where you can see I'm getting NA values for logFC and zscore columns:
head(circ)
  category         ID                                           term count
1       BP GO:0070371                          ERK1 and ERK2 cascade     1
2       BP GO:0070372            regulation of ERK1 and ERK2 cascade     1
3       BP GO:0030217                         T cell differentiation     1
4       BP GO:0060326                                cell chemotaxis     1
5       BP GO:0032680 regulation of tumor necrosis factor production     1
6       BP GO:0002237       response to molecule of bacterial origin     1
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            genes
1 ENSMUSG00000000982/ENSMUSG00000002603/ENSMUSG00000003032/ENSMUSG00000004814/ENSMUSG00000006445/ENSMUSG00000018930/ENSMUSG00000019122/ENSMUSG00000019960/ENSMUSG00000019997/ENSMUSG00000020357/ENSMUSG00000021127/ENSMUSG00000022309/ENSMUSG00000022346/ENSMUSG00000026628/ENSMUSG00000027399/ENSMUSG00000027765/ENSMUSG00000027995/ENSMUSG00000028195/ENSMUSG00000029163/ENSMUSG00000031530/ENSMUSG00000035352/ENSMUSG00000035373/ENSMUSG00000035385/ENSMUSG00000037405/ENSMUSG00000038058/ENSMUSG00000039384/ENSMUSG00000042567/ENSMUSG00000048779/ENSMUSG00000049130/ENSMUSG00000051212/ENSMUSG00000054204/ENSMUSG00000062960
2                                       ENSMUSG00000000982/ENSMUSG00000002603/ENSMUSG00000003032/ENSMUSG00000004814/ENSMUSG00000006445/ENSMUSG00000018930/ENSMUSG00000019122/ENSMUSG00000019960/ENSMUSG00000019997/ENSMUSG00000020357/ENSMUSG00000022309/ENSMUSG00000026628/ENSMUSG00000027399/ENSMUSG00000027765/ENSMUSG00000027995/ENSMUSG00000028195/ENSMUSG00000029163/ENSMUSG00000031530/ENSMUSG00000035352/ENSMUSG00000035373/ENSMUSG00000035385/ENSMUSG00000037405/ENSMUSG00000038058/ENSMUSG00000039384/ENSMUSG00000042567/ENSMUSG00000048779/ENSMUSG00000049130/ENSMUSG00000051212/ENSMUSG00000054204/ENSMUSG00000062960
3                                                                                                ENSMUSG00000002111/ENSMUSG00000002603/ENSMUSG00000004951/ENSMUSG00000015396/ENSMUSG00000015605/ENSMUSG00000021127/ENSMUSG00000021453/ENSMUSG00000022952/ENSMUSG00000024659/ENSMUSG00000026162/ENSMUSG00000027399/ENSMUSG00000028150/ENSMUSG00000029135/ENSMUSG00000030124/ENSMUSG00000030528/ENSMUSG00000034686/ENSMUSG00000035356/ENSMUSG00000036931/ENSMUSG00000037370/ENSMUSG00000038418/ENSMUSG00000039384/ENSMUSG00000042677/ENSMUSG00000043505/ENSMUSG00000044258/ENSMUSG00000051212/ENSMUSG00000053175/ENSMUSG00000063415
4                                                                                                                   ENSMUSG00000000982/ENSMUSG00000002111/ENSMUSG00000004814/ENSMUSG00000004951/ENSMUSG00000006445/ENSMUSG00000018920/ENSMUSG00000018930/ENSMUSG00000019122/ENSMUSG00000023034/ENSMUSG00000024659/ENSMUSG00000033220/ENSMUSG00000034855/ENSMUSG00000035352/ENSMUSG00000035373/ENSMUSG00000035385/ENSMUSG00000040152/ENSMUSG00000040552/ENSMUSG00000043953/ENSMUSG00000044534/ENSMUSG00000049130/ENSMUSG00000050370/ENSMUSG00000051212/ENSMUSG00000054717/ENSMUSG00000058427/ENSMUSG00000062960/ENSMUSG00000079227
5                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ENSMUSG00000000982/ENSMUSG00000002603/ENSMUSG00000004951/ENSMUSG00000018930/ENSMUSG00000022309/ENSMUSG00000027399/ENSMUSG00000027995/ENSMUSG00000028195/ENSMUSG00000030921/ENSMUSG00000035385/ENSMUSG00000037447/ENSMUSG00000038058/ENSMUSG00000040152/ENSMUSG00000040794/ENSMUSG00000042677/ENSMUSG00000044786/ENSMUSG00000051439/ENSMUSG00000053175/ENSMUSG00000073406/ENSMUSG00000073409/ENSMUSG00000079227
6                                                          ENSMUSG00000002111/ENSMUSG00000018920/ENSMUSG00000019256/ENSMUSG00000022500/ENSMUSG00000022901/ENSMUSG00000023034/ENSMUSG00000027399/ENSMUSG00000027995/ENSMUSG00000029135/ENSMUSG00000030921/ENSMUSG00000032369/ENSMUSG00000032372/ENSMUSG00000032377/ENSMUSG00000032487/ENSMUSG00000034855/ENSMUSG00000035356/ENSMUSG00000035385/ENSMUSG00000037447/ENSMUSG00000037580/ENSMUSG00000039384/ENSMUSG00000041605/ENSMUSG00000042677/ENSMUSG00000044786/ENSMUSG00000049130/ENSMUSG00000049625/ENSMUSG00000051439/ENSMUSG00000054717/ENSMUSG00000056501/ENSMUSG00000058427
  logFC adj_pval zscore
1    NA 2.99e-09     NA
2    NA 7.23e-09     NA
3    NA 6.03e-07     NA
4    NA 7.28e-07     NA
5    NA 7.28e-07     NA
6    NA 7.28e-07     NA

I'm providing appropriate data for this in the input data files, as seen below:
head(genelist)
               ID  baseMean      logFC      lfcSE      stat       pvalue    adj.P.Val
1 ENSMUSG00000000555  194.8234  0.8937636 0.25189607  3.548144 3.879560e-04 1.301399e-02
2 ENSMUSG00000000686   41.1447 -0.6175972 0.37424955 -1.650228 9.889623e-02 2.998447e-01
3 ENSMUSG00000000982  116.3638  5.7609094 0.75933093  7.586823 3.280000e-14 1.860000e-11
4 ENSMUSG00000001034  635.4174 -0.6153160 0.13473524 -4.566853 4.950000e-06 5.475510e-04
5 ENSMUSG00000001473  370.8013  0.7989403 0.19145612  4.172968 3.010000e-05 2.216721e-03
6 ENSMUSG00000001627 3310.3776  0.7071353 0.09953138  7.104646 1.210000e-12 5.340000e-10

I don't get an error from this code, it successfully runs and outputs a figure. The issue is the the figure isn't mapping the genes to the GO terms on the GO circle i.e. it isn't reading fold changes or zscores to plot onto the graph:

This is clearly an issue within my two data files somewhere, but I've set them up according to the GOplot package github page, so I'm really not sure where I've gone wrong.
I've followed the GOplot github instructions. I've successfully gotten the code to run, but its just not pulling the information from my data files correctly.

Are you able to provide sample data for both files? In the documentation, the example circle_dat(EC$david, EC$genelist) outputs a column of counts and a column of individual genes. head(circ) above looks different: showing counts of 1 and long strings of genes.

Hey! I actually figured out the issue. It's that my GO analysis data file had the ENSEMBL ID's separated by slashes (/), whereas the GOplot package relies on DAVID GO analysis which outputs the ENSEMBL ID's separated by commas. Once I inserted code to replace all the slashes with commas, it was able to read the data correctly. Thanks!
